# Interpreting the coefficient of a Normal GLMM in terms of a percentage

Tags: confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, interpretation

Here is the setting of the problem:

> There is an examination that students (indexed by $i$) can take once annually in a three-year program. Students are **not** obligated to take this examination each year, but are required to take it at least once over the three years.
>
> A student could (but is **not** obligated to) take an exam-prep class of sorts either before or after an exam at time $t$ (indicated by $\alpha_{it}$) and may be in years 1, 2, or 3 of the program (indicated by $\beta_{it}$). For our purposes, if student $i$ never takes the prep class, $\alpha_{it} = 0$ for all $t$. The value $t$ indicates the calendar year in which the exam was taken, distinct from the year the student is in the program.

I've chosen to model this situation as a generalized linear mixed-effects model

$$\log\left(\dfrac{\mu_{it}}{1-\mu_{it}}\right)=\mu + b_1\alpha_{it}+\gamma_i+\delta_t$$

where

- $y_{it} \in (0, 1)$ is the exam score expressed as a percentage of the $i$th student at time $t$ (truncated from above at 0.999) which is normally distributed with mean $\mu_{it}$,
- $\mu$ is an intercept,
- $\alpha_{it} \in \{0, 1\}$ (a binary indicator equalling $1$ if an exam-prep class was taken before taking the exam at time $t$),
- $\gamma_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2_{\gamma})$ is a random effect used to incorporate student-to-student variability,
- $\delta_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2_{\delta})$ is a random effect used to incorporate exam-to-exam variability.

You may assume I've done my due diligence to assess the reasonableness of these assumptions.

> **My goal is the following: to make a claim that taking an exam-prep class before an exam is associated with an increase/decrease in $\mu_{it}$ by X percent.**

So let's do some mathematics here. What we have here are two regression models:

$$
\begin{align}
&\log\left(\dfrac{\tilde\mu_{it}}{1-\tilde\mu_{it}}\right)=\mu + b_1+\gamma_i+\delta_t\tag{1} \\
&\log\left(\dfrac{\hat\mu_{it}}{1-\hat\mu_{it}}\right)=\mu + \gamma_i+\delta_t\tag{2}
\end{align}$$
and taking (1) - (2) gives

$$\log\left(\dfrac{\tilde\mu_{it}}{1-\tilde\mu_{it}}\right) - \log\left(\dfrac{\hat\mu_{it}}{1-\hat\mu_{it}}\right) = b_1$$

so $b_1$ can be interpreted as a difference of the log-odds of the exam scores (a bit of a strange quantity to interpret).

Is there any way this could be at least approximated to a difference of proportions, ideally with a confidence interval? If so, what could I cite to justify this?

**EDIT**: We could also use the fact that

$$\dfrac{\tilde\mu_{it}}{1-\tilde\mu_{it}}\exp(b_1) = \dfrac{\hat\mu_{it}}{1-\hat\mu_{it}}$$
and using a Taylor series expansion centered at 0, we have $f(x) \approx 1 + x$ so
$$(1+\tilde\mu_{it})\exp(b_1) = 1 - \hat{\mu}_{it}$$
and
$$ \exp(b_1)\tilde{\mu}_{it} - \hat{\mu}_{it} = \exp(b_1) - 1$$
but this is the closest I can get.

Note that $\hat{b}_1 = 0.27502$, so I suppose I could say that $\exp(b_1) \approx 1$ and use this for the left-hand side only, but this may be too crude of an approximation (plus I don't feel great about using $\exp(b_1) \approx 1$ for the left-hand side but not the right-hand side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was making this question *way* too complicated.

Suppose we have estimators $\hat\mu$ and $\hat{b}_1$ for $\mu$ and $b_1$ respectively.

Then letting $g(\alpha_{it}) = \dfrac{\exp(\hat\mu + \hat b_1 \alpha_{it})}{1 + \exp(\hat\mu + \hat b_1\alpha_{it})}$, we can simply use the difference $g(1) - g(0)$.

This makes sense since we have to hold all other variables constant in interpreting parameters.

Agresti uses similar methodology in Example 5.1.3 of *Categorical Data Analysis*, 3rd edition (pp. 166-168).