# Citation for deviance on generalized linear mixed-effects models

Tags: mixed-model, references, deviance

All examples I've found on deviance tests being performed are on generalized linear models. Is there something I can cite validating the use of deviance tests for generalized linear mixed-effects models with normal random effects, ideally outlining what the procedure looks like?

Added from the comments:

This is for submission for a peer-reviewed journal whose primary audience is MDs who are not statistically inclined. I am trying to justify my model selection method for inference. You can find my writeup of the situation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476534/interpreting-the-coefficient-of-a-normal-glmm-in-terms-of-a-percentage), except there is an additional term $b_2\beta_{it}$ in the model, as well as the possibility of an interation term $b_3\alpha_{it}\beta_{it}$. I used deviance testing to compare nested models which all contained the two random effects in that model, to justify which fixed effects to use, and whether or not to use the interaction term.

Comment: What is your purpose for performing such a procedure ? Many things that are well defined for linear and generalised linear models do not carry across to mixed models.

Comment: @RobertLong Good question. Keep in mind this is for submission for a peer-reviewed journal whose primary audience is MDs who are not statistically inclined. I am trying to justify my model selection method for inference. You can find my writeup of the situation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476534/interpreting-the-coefficient-of-a-normal-glmm-in-terms-of-a-percentage), except there is an additional term $b_2\beta_{it}$. I used deviance testing to compare nested models which all contained the two random effects in that writeup, and to justify which fixed effects to use.

Comment: @RobertLong I've clarified this in the original question. Thanks.

Comment: OK I've read your other post (+1 for both btw). So, exams and students are partially crossed ? And if I've understood correctly you want to justify the inclusion of fixed effects based on some test ? Maybe I'm mising something, but why not just use a likelihood ratio test ?

Comment: @RobertLong Yes for exams and students being partially crossed. I suppose my only justification for that is that deviance tests are built into R for generalized linear mixed-effects models. It's simple to do, and... let's just say I don't want to make this more complicated for the intended audience.

Comment: @RobertLong If it's impossible to find a citation for deviance, I'll figure out how to do a LRT in R with these models.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"deviance tests are built into R for generalized linear mixed-effects models."*

Comment: @RobertLong Now I'm wondering if my methodology is wrong. I used `glmer()` from the `lme4` package to specify the generalized linear-mixed effects models, and then did `anova(m0, m1, m2, m3)` for example, where `m0`, etc. are the nested models.

Comment: That's a likelihood ratio test :)

Comment: @RobertLong What's the difference between deviance tests with nested models, and a likelihood ratio test?

Comment: @RobertLong Thank you so much, by the way.

Comment: Well, I'll have to be honest and say I'm not sure what a deviance test is. I've not (knowingly) come across the term before. A little googling suggests that it might be the same as a likelihood ratio test in the case of *generalised* linear models.

Comment: @RobertLong Thanks so much! I imagine I'm going to have a much easier time finding a citation for LRTs with generalized linear mixed-effects models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context the "deviance test" is another term for "likelihood ratio test" (LRT)

LRTs are well understood as a means to compare mixed effects models with different fixed effects, provided they are fitted with maximum likelihood, rather than restricted maximum likelihood.

In terms of references I don't think you need anything specifically related to mixed models, since your random structure is the same, and you are testing models with different fixed effects. So, the standard references for generalized linear models ought to suffice. For example:

McCullagh P, Nelder J (1989). Generalized Linear Models. Chapman & Hall/CRC, London.

Da Silva DN, Cordeiro GM (2009). "A Computer Program to Improve LR Tests for Generalized Linear Models." Communications in Statistics – Simulation and Computation, 38(10), 2184–2197.